# Getting Intra-Maps roam to interface with internal GPS

Tags: gps, intramaps-roam

I've got Intramaps Roam installed on a Panasonic Toughpad fz-g1 with integrated u-blox M8 gps.

When I open up GPSviewer I can see my position, everything seems fine. When I enable GPS with intra-maps roam, it says 'GPS Active' but the lat lon reading is 0,0.

I'm connected on COM3 with 9600bps.

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been patched in a newer (unreleased) version of Roam.  You can build Roam from source if you want to try it out, or grab a build from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuh9xkqe6pxv3kr/IntraMaps%20Roam.zip?dl=0)

It seems those GPS get the GLONASS messages as well as the normal GPS ones.  The GPS module in QGIS didn't handle both of the messages. I have patch Roam to handle both.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question. I'll update when I get a chance to install the latest version.

Comment: After building from source everything worked as expected. Thank you!